# How to extract break time from faulttime

Tags: mysql

I have `faultdata` table which contains `faultstartrtc` and `clearrtc` columns.

Another table is `breaktime` which has columns `beakstartrtc` and `breakendrtc`. I want to calculate sum of fault duration excluding break time period. Can i achieve this in query ?
I tried sub query

```
SELECT * FROM faultdata3
WHERE faultstartrtc=(
  SELECT MAX(faultstartrtc) FROM faultdata3 
  WHERE faultstartrtc <='2013-11-23 11:00:00'
)
OR faultclearrtc=(
  SELECT MIN(faultclearrtc) FROM faultdata3
  WHERE faultclearrtc>='2013-11-23 11:30:00'
)
```

But it returns me that row which is nearest to this time. Also if it returns

```
faultstartrtc        faultclearrtc
2013-11-23 10:30:00  2013-11-23 12:00:00
```

then how to extract period between  11:00 to 11:30 from this ?

Comment: Could you provide `show create table faultdata3;` and `show create table breaktime;` table descriptions? And sample data if possible.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Did my answer help you in any way?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have this timeline :

```
10:00 Everything is OK
10:15 Fault start RTC
10:30 Break start RTC
11:00 Break end RTC
12:00 Fault end RTC
12:01 Everything is OK
```

So

- Fault duration is 10:15 -> 12:00 = 1h45min
- Break duration is 10:30 -> 11:00 = 0h30min
- Fault - Break duration is 1h45min - 0h30min = 1h15min

So here is how I see it :

```
SELECT
faultstartrtc,
faultendrtc,
TIMEDIFF(faultendrtc,faultstartrtc) as faultduration,

( SELECT TIMEDIFF(breakendrtc,breakstartrtc) as breakduration
    FROM breaktime
    WHERE breakstartrtc>faultstartrtc
    AND breakendrtc<faultendrtc
) as breakduration,

TIMEDIFF(
    TIMEDIFF(faultendrtc,faultstartrtc),
    ( SELECT TIMEDIFF(breakendrtc,breakstartrtc) 
        FROM breaktime
        WHERE breakstartrtc>faultstartrtc
        AND breakendrtc<faultendrtc
    )
)
as faultwithoutbreakduration

FROM faultdata3
WHERE 
DATE(faultstartrtc) ='2013-11-23'
```

My `WHERE` is a bit random, to detect faults that happened on Novembre 23th 2013.

Tell me if you understand my query.